# PyZMQ segmentation fault, messages not arriving after restart via bash script

Tags: multithreading, sockets, python-multiprocessing, zeromq, pyzmq

im currently facing an issue in which a proxy throws a segmentation error after a random period of time. Restarting the proxy with a bash script leads to messages not arriving.
I was sadly not able to recreate the issue. I am aware that this most likely is related to a partly wrong utilization of zmq and that the error gets thrown by c python.

The System runs 3 diffrent processes.

1. process, which task is to handle send data, which is a subscriber

```
context = zmq.Context()
socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)
socket.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:8100")
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, b'')
poller = zmq.Poller()
poller.register(socket, zmq.POLLIN)

while True:
    try:
        socks = dict(poller.poll())

        if socket in socks and socks[socket] == zmq.POLLIN:
            action, values = socket.recv_pyobj()
            ##### handling of data #######

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
```

2. process, being a proxy

```
def main():
    context = zmq.Context()

    # Socket facing clients
    frontend = context.socket(zmq.XSUB)
    frontend.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")

    # Socket facing services
    backend = context.socket(zmq.XPUB)
    backend.bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:8100")

    print("starting broker...")
    while True:
        try:
            zmq.proxy(frontend, backend)
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            print("stopping broker...")
            frontend.close()
            backend.close()
            context.term()
            quit()
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"failed with {e}")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

3. process running multiple threads which publish their data.

```
socket_pub = context.socket(zmq.PUB)
socket_pub.connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:5557")
while True:
    # pre processing f.e. outgoing requests
    ######

    # sending results
    message = ["Action", {"foo": "bar"}]
    socket_pub.send_pyobj(message)
```

As i was not able to recreate the error and therefor was not able to fix it i am trying to bypass it using a bash script.
The segementation error gets thrown in process nr. 2 (the proxy).
Thus the bash script simply restarts it.

```
#!/bin/bash
until python3 process2.py; do
    echo "bridge broker crashed with exit code $?.  Respawning.." >&2
    sleep 1
done
```

The bash script correctly respawns the process if it died due to a segmentation fault.
But notifications from process 3 are not arriving in process 1 anymore.

I was not able to track down why this is happening. I rebuild it localy and if i manually restarted the proxy (without a segmentation fault) the messages directly arrived again.

Does anybody have a clue why this is happening or do i have to find the initial reason for the segmentation fault?

Comment: When you manually restart the proxy, the ZeroMQ sockets are closed correctly and the publishers will detect that because the underlying TCP connection is closed correctly. That does not happen when the proxy segfaults. You might be able to get similar behavior if you terminate the proxy with `kill -9`.

Comment: I just tryd that sadly this way the proxy reconnected properly and messages were arriving